# My iPad is connected to my Mac's Wi-Fi, but can't connect to the Internet

Tags: ipad, wifi, network, internet-sharing

I have a Mac which is connected to the Internet via Ethernet. I've used the "create network" facility on it to create a Wi-Fi network.

I opened up my iPad's settings and connected to that Wi-Fi network.

But when I try to connect to browse using Safari on the iPad I get, "Cannot open page -- Safari cannot open the page because it is not connected to the Internet".

Any way I can get on the Web with this iPad?

Comment: Is Internet connection sharing enabled on the Mac?

Comment: Is there any easy way to see what IP address the iPad is getting? If it's self-assigned (usually starting with 69.*) then you are not truly connected to that wifi network.  One way to confirm is to see if you can access the broadcasting Mac's shared files.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. @Randolph West Yes, Internet connection sharing is enabled. Anthony -- thanks, I'll look into that.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to work by restarting everything -- computer, iPad, router, and cable modem.

Comment: You went nuclear.